# How to destroy MockRestServiceServer?

Tags: rest, unit-testing, spring-test

We are using RestTemplate to consume external rest services. There lot of different kinds of services in our project and all of them are tested using different strategies like mocking rest template and mocking our communication object.

We have used below code in our test case to test one service using MockRestServiceServer :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
```

So our question is :
Is there a way to destroy this server as soon as this test case completes so this doesn't affect other test cases?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First and foremost, the `MockRestServiceServer` is not a real server -- for example, it is not listening on a TCP port. The only thing the `MockRestServiceServer` does is modify your `RestTemplate` (see details below).

So to answer your question: there is no server to *destroy*.

However... if your `RestTemplate` is created in your `ApplicationContext` and injected into multiple components (e.g., in your service layer), you may want to reset the initial state of the `RestTemplate`. If that's the case, read on...

There is currently no "official" way to *reset* the `RestTemplate` passed to `MockRestServiceServer.createServer()`, but that doesn't mean you can't implement such a feature on your own.

The key to understanding this is knowing that the `MockRestServiceServer.createServer()` method replaces the `ClientHttpRequestFactory` in the provided `RestTemplate` with a *mocked* version (i.e., the private, internal `MockRestServiceServer.RequestMatcherClientHttpRequestFactory`).

So you should be able to *reset* the original state of the `RestTemplate` by tracking the original request factory and setting it in the template after your test. Something like the following should work:

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = // likely injected into the test
ClientHttpRequestFactory originalRequestFactory = restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);

try {
    // use mockServer as usual...

    mockServer.verify();
} finally {
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(originalRequestFactory);
}
```

Let me know if that solves your problem!

Cheers,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Thanks lot. This works like a charm. Thank you for detailed explanation.

Comment: @TusharPatel you should mark as Accepted this answer :)

Comment: Can we use reset instead of the method above https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html#reset--? Not sure when this question was posted, the library was having that method or not.

Comment: No. `MockRestServiceServer.reset()` resets the expectations (in the underlying `RequestExpectationManager`). It does not reset the `ClientHttpRequestFactory` in the `RestTemplate`.